# Why time.mktime and datetime.timestamp generate different timestamps with the same date string input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert the date string to timestamp but through implementing the following ways, I get different results:

```
import time
import datetime

date = "11/10/2020"

# First way
print(time.mktime(time.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")))

# Second way
print(datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")))
```

Output:

```
1602370800.0
1604966400.0
```

Why don't they generate the same outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to process the date/month/year in the same format in both cases to achieve the same result, as in the first case you are taking it as `%d/%m/%Y` while in case 2 you are processing it as `%m/%d/%Y`. this is making the whole difference

make the processing format the same and you will see the same result